# Must set build.dir error in project

Tags: java, xml, ant, build

So, I'm running a java+xml program as my project (Generate timetable using Genetic Algorithm). So, right now I have problem in my xml. My java code all has no error.

So, I have build-impl.xml, project.xml, and build.xml. I'm running in eclipse macbook pro late 2010.
This program is originally build for netbeans so you might see the words netbeans.

I got this error. "Users/admin/eclipse/workspace/GA_TestBench/src/nbproject/build-impl.xml:137: Must set build.dir"

Where do I edit the to set build.dir? It is in project.xml like I did for src.dir

My coding for project.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/project/1">
   <property name="src.dir"     value="/Users/admin/eclipse/workspace/GA_TestBench/src"/>
   <type>org.eclipse.modules.java.j2seproject</type>
   <configuration>
    <data xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3">
        <name>GA_TestBench</name>

        <source-roots>
            <root 
            id="src.dir"/>
       </source-roots>
        <test-roots>
    <root id="test.src.dir" 
    <!--  "src.dir"="/Users/admin/eclipse/workspace/GA_TestBench/src.dir "/>-->
    </test-roots>
    </data>
    </configuration>
    </project>
```

**My coding for build.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="GA_TestBench" default="default" basedir=".">
    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="test.src.dir" value="test"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="classes"/>
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project GA_TestBench.</description>
<import file="/Users/admin/eclipse/workspace/GA_TestBench/src/nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
```

My coding for build-impl.xml is here the link. I'm sorry i can't post since it exceeds character that i can. https://code.google.com/p/csc384-genetic-algorithms-project/source/browse/trunk/GA_TestBench/nbproject/build-impl.xml?r=30

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add the code from build-impl.xml to your question?

Comment: I given the link to the file. thank you. @randomducks

Comment: What is the loglevel of your ant build ?

Comment: You made a radical edit in your question, which invalidates the answers. I am rolling back your original question. You should create a new question (not overwrite the previous one).

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I'll remember that. Hehee.

Answer (score 1):

The `build.dir` property usually contains a local relative path to the directory in the file system where project files will be generated (class files, generated code, etc.) Other subdirectories may be used relative to it. It is *usually* called *build*, but it could actually be any path you want. Normally your *classes.dir* would be something like `${build.dir}/classes` (which in the file that you linked seems to be the `build.classes.dir`.

You can set any property through a system property in the command line:

```
ant -Dbuild.dir=path-to-build-dir ...
```

as a property in a property file, where you can declare properties in the form `build.dir=value`

```
<property file="some-file.properties"/>
```

or using an element such as

```
<property name="build.dir" value="path"/>
```

just like you did with the other properties.

There error is from this line in your linked code which checks if the `build.dir` property was set:

```
<fail unless="build.dir">Must set build.dir</fail>
```

It should have been set *before* that line is executed.

You can set it safely in your *build.xml* before importing anything, since properties are only set *once*.

Comment: thank you very much. i run the coding in netbeans and it works well. said build successful but no output been made. can you help me?